# pandas change column value and change another column value based on this

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe and want to add 'NaN' to values '1' and '2' under the 'DROP' column and change the corresponding 'MEAN' column values to 'NaN' as well.

```
print (df)
   Flow  DROP   MEAN
0     1     0  0.025
1     2     1  2.900
2     3     2  2.800
3     4     0  0.020
```

After:

```
print (df)
   Flow  DROP   MEAN
0     1   0.0  0.025
1     2   NaN    NaN
2     3   NaN    NaN
3     4   0.0  0.020
```

Comment: What did you try? Show minimal example.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Sorry about that! I'm new here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with condition by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df.loc[df['DROP'].isin([1,2]), ['DROP','MEAN']] = np.nan
```

Or by compare value for not equal to `0`:

```
df.loc[df['DROP'] != 0, ['DROP','MEAN']] = np.nan
```

Comment: Hi, I can't seem to create it as another df, as I need to create more dfs. df1= (df.loc[df['DROP'].isin([1,2]), ['DROP','MEAN']] = np.nan) df2= (df.loc[df['DROP'].isin([0,2]), ['DROP','MEAN']] = np.nan) df3= (df.loc[df['DROP'].isin([0,1]), ['DROP','MEAN']] = np.nan)

Comment: No error in your code. I tried modifying it as above but getting invalid syntax error.   I was modifying so I can make it into a new Dataframe (df1) as I need to create 2 more new Dataframes, df2 will have make DROP values 0 & 2 NaN and the corresponding MEAN values NaN. And df3 will make DROP values 0 & 1 NaN and the corresponding MEAN values NaN.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['DROP'], df['MEAN'] = np.where(df.DROP != 0, np.nan, df['DROP']), np.where(df.DROP != 0, np.nan, df['MEAN'])
```

Result:

```
   Flow  DROP   MEAN
0     1   0.0  0.025
1     2   NaN    NaN
2     3   NaN    NaN
3     4   0.0  0.020
```